# GeckoFX45 How to Install unsigned extensions *.XPI?

Tags: geckofx

I want to install http://mozilla.github.io/shumway/extension/firefox/shumway.xpi in GeckoFX 45. How do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly because Firefox extensions are largely based around the interface and working of Firefox's UI, not just the Gecko interface, I don't think it would be possible at all currently to install extensions or .XPI files.

Comment: To add: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/69/how-to-add-firefox-extensions-to-gecko

Answer (score 0):

If you still need this, or anyone else:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct

At the bottom:

Override add-on signing (advanced users)

You can temporarily override the setting to enforce the add-on signing requirement by changing the preference `xpinstall.signatures.required` to false in the Firefox Configuration Editor (`about:config` page). Support is not available for any changes made with the Configuration Editor so please do this at your own risk.

Comment: I know about it, how install any xpi to Firefox. But I can't do it for GeckoFX45 (https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0) .